# Limpar a variável de cidades ao selecionar um outro estado

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma pequena dúvida.

> Tenho uma view que quando o usuário seleciona um estado, carrega a lista de cidades do banco de dados. Mas está tendo dois problemas:
>
> 1. Quando seleciona o estado, a cidade selecionada é uma qualquer, não a primeira da lista.
> 2. Quando um estado está selecionado, e já carregou suas cidades, se seleciono outro estado, ele mostra os estados do novo estado selecionado e do anterior, não estou conseguindo fazer mostrar apenas os estados do novo estado selecionado.

#### Meu código:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estado</label>
        <select id="uf" onchange="return buscarMunicipios();" name="uf" type="text" class="form-control upper @error('uf') is-invalid @enderror" required>
            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                @foreach($states as $state)
            <option value="{{$state->id }}" {{ old('uf') == $state->title ? 'selected' : '' }}>{!!$state->title!!}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cidade</label>
        <select id="cidade" name="cidade" type="text" class="form-control upper @error('cidade') is-invalid @enderror" required>
            <option value="">Selecione</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller:

```
public function buscarMunicipios() {
        $estado_id = \Request::input('estado_id');
        $cidades = State::findOrFail($estado_id)->cities->sortBy('titl');
        $result = json_encode(['cidades'=>$cidades]);

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

#### Js:

```
function buscarMunicipios() {

    var token = $("#token").val();
    var estado_id = $("#uf").val();
    console.log('estado id'+estado_id);
    //    var json = stringToJson(colaboradores);
    //    console.log(json);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/painel/clientes/busca-municipio',
        type: 'POST',
        method: 'POST',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
        data: {'_token': token,'estado_id': estado_id},
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (response) {


            response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response.cidades);

            $.each(response.cidades,
                function (index, cidade) {
                    $("#cidade").append("<option selected value=" + cidade.id + ">" + cidade.title + "</option>");
                });

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Não recomendo que traga a primeira cidade selecionada, isso pode induzir o usuário ao erro de selecionar uma cidade indesejada, portanto deixe selecionado uma opção "Selecione uma cidade" (`selected`) e como não selecionável (`disabled`) caso seja obrigatório (se não for obrigatória desconsidere o `disabled` nesta  opção).

A primeira coisa que você vai precisar fazer é limpar a lista de cidades sempre que um novo estado for selecionado (isso deve estar no início da sua função)

```
$("#cidade").html("<option selected disabled>Selecione</option>")
```

Após essa limpeza, você estará pronto para adicionar as novas cidades ao seu <kbd>select</kbd>. com os dados do success no seu Ajax